# Why did my question get edited?

Tags: discussion

Why was [my question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116161/getting-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-sdl2) (now deleted) edited?

Comment: Meta is the place to ask these sorts of questions, not the main site. Furthermore, it is very possible to ask the question you have without insulting other users; such behavior is not tolerated. I've removed the offending parts of your question as well as the gibberish.

Answer (score 5):

The original title of your question was "Pixel formats are hard! Getting the color of a pixel in SDL2." The title was edited to remove the "pixel formats are hard" prefix, presumably because the editor (correctly) considered it noise.

Titles are a key factor in the searching of questions and are thus better when they are concise and accurately describe the problem at hand.

The other edits to your question consisted of minor body edits to similarly focus the question on the problem of needing to access pixel values in SDL.

Remember that on StackExchange, you don't "own" the content of your posts in the sense of having exclusive control over them; this is a collaborative site where anyone with sufficient reputation can edit your posts to improve them, correct minor issues, or otherwise align them with the goals and policies of the site.

The correct place to raise questions about this when you are unsure about it is here, on meta. You shouldn't do it on the main site, and you shouldn't do it by insulting other users and filling your post with unrelated poetry. Please remember that.

The [help center](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/help) has more information.